# Getting parent of new tab after adding to bound TabControl (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I'm adding a close button to my tabs using the following guide:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84213/How-to-add-a-Close-button-to-a-WPF-TabItem

This has become a problem because the event uses the 'parent' of the added tab to remove that tab from the tabcontrol.  I'm binding the tab control using mvvm, so the parent property is apparently not being set and giving me a null reference exception for the parent when the event tries to remove from it.

Here's the binding so you get the idea:

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" Margin="0,22,0.2,-5.2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" Background="#FF4C76B2"/>
```

Heres where the tabs are being added.

```
private void AddTab(object tabName)
{
    ClosableTab newTab = new ClosableTab();
    newTab.Title = "title?";
    //newTab.Header = tabName;
    TextBox test = new TextBox();

    test.Text = "CONTENT (" + tabName + ") GOES HERE";
    newTab.Content = test;

    Tabs.Add(newTab);
    OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
}
```

Here is the event where the null reference is taking place:

```
void button_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TabControl)this.Parent).Items.Remove(this);
}
```

As I see it there are two options:

- try to find another way to remove the tab (without the parent
  property)
- try to find a way to somehow set the parent property (which cant be
  done directly, it throws a compiler error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't sound like MVVM to me. We work with *data*, not *UI elements*. We work with collections of classes that contain all of the properties required to fulfil some requirement and data bind those properties to the UI controls in `DataTemplate`s. In this way, we add UI controls by adding data items into these collections and let the wonderful WPF templating system take care of the UI.

For example, you have a `TabControl` that we want to add or remove `TabItem`s from... in a proper MVVM way. First, we need a collection of items that can represent each `TabItem`:

```
public static DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(TestView));

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

I'm just using a `DependencyProperty` because I knocked this up in a `UserControl` and I'm just using a collection of `string`s for simplicity. You'll need to create a class that contains *all* of the data required for the whole `TabItem` content. Next, let's see the `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" />
```

We data bind the collection to the `TabControl.ItemsSource` property and we set the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` to a `Resource` named `ItemTemplate`. Let's see that now:

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type System:String}">
    <TabItem Header="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This `DataTemplate` defines what each item in our collection will look like. For simplicity's sake, our `string`s are just data bound to the `TabItem.Header` property. This means that for each item we add into the collection, we'll now get a new `TabItem` with its `Header` property set to the value of the `string`:

```
Items.Add("Tab 1");
Items.Add("Tab 2");
Items.Add("Tab 3");
```

Note that I included the `System` XML Namespace Prefix for completeness, but you won't need that because your `DataType` will be your own custom class. You'll need more `DataTemplate`s too. For example, if your custom class had a `Header` property and a `Content` property, which was another custom class, let's say called `Content`, that contained all of the properties for the `TabItem.Content` property, you could do this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:YourClass}">
    <TabItem Header="{Binding Header}" Content="{Binding Content}" />
</DataTemplate> 
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:Content}">
    <YourPrefix:SomeUserControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

So this would give you `TabItem`s with `Header`s set and `Content` that comes from `SomeUserControl` which you could design. You don't need to use `UserControl`s, you could just add more UI controls to either `DataTemplate`. But you will need to add more controls somewhere... and more classes and properties, always remembering to correctly implement the essential [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

And finally, to answer your question in the proper MVVM way... to remove a `TabItem`, you simply remove the item that relates to that `TabItem` from the collection. Simple... or it would have been if you really had been using MVVM like you claim. It's really worth learning MVVM properly as you'll soon see the benefits. I'll leave you to find your own tutorials as there are many to chose from.

---

UPDATE >>>

Your event handling is still not so MVVM... you don't need to pass a reference of any view model anywhere. The MVVM way is to use commands in the view model. In particular, you should investigate the `RelayCommand`. I have my own version, but these commands enable us to perform actions from data bound `Button`s and other UI controls using methods or inline `delegate`s in the view model (where `action` and `canExecute` in this example are the `CommandParameter` values):

```
<Button Content="Close Tab" Command="{Binding CloseTabCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />

...

public ICommand CloseTabCommand
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => Items.Remove(action), 
        canExecute => canExecute != null && Items.Contains(canExecute)); }
}
```

So whatever view model has your `Tabs` collection should have an `AddTabCommand` and a `CloseTabCommand` that add and remove items from the `Tabs` collection. But just to be clear, for this to work properly, your `ClosableTab` class should be a data class and not a UI control class. Use a `DataTemplate` to specify it if it is a UI control.

You can find out about the `RelayCommand` from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) on MSDN.

Comment: The Observable collection that I bound the itemsSource is 'Tabs' in the code above.

As for just removing from the collection, yea that's what I ended up doing (although I don't like that I had to pass a reference of my viewmodel to get the Tabs property from it)